# Allow a user to make changes to a google sheet, but have these changes not apply to other users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a basic two tab (sheets) spreadsheet.  One tab stores a lot of data.  The other tab is the front end / user interface that contains some drop down menus that a single, long query formula uses to populate a user generated query.

The problem is that this spreadsheet sees a lot of users and that one user's query actively changes the query results while another user is trying to view her query results.

Implementing a "filter view" is not a solution because users are actually editing data (the drop down menus) to generate a query.

I do not want to have users create their own copy of the spreadsheet as I am concerned they will return to the copy and not the master and not see recent changes to the data.

Comment: No, implementing a filter view **is** the exact solution for that case - many users, each wants to see something different. The issue is that your front-end implementation is not suited for your goal. You need to change your approach, such as write a sidebar that has the dropdowns, and this sidebar's "Execute Query" button generates and applies a FilterView for that user with the desired parameters. The real solution is to use a database as your database, instead of a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Make copies but don't have the data in the copies. The data tab in the copies should have an `importrange()` that pulls the data in from your master sheet.

The data in the copies will stay uptodate and you should not have to rework your front end any.

It would still be a pain to update the front end since you'd have to hunt down all the copies.

This should function but you may want to investigate a more suitable tool for this task. possibly: datastudio.google.com/

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340

Answer (score 0):

Make a sheet for each user.

You could do this on one spreadsheet having all the sheets together or by creating a new spreadsheet for each user.

If you put all the sheets on the same spreadsheet, protect them to make that only the corresponding user is able to edit each sheet.

Regarding your concern, having one spreadsheet by each user, make the copies by yourself and keep the ownership of them.